# Curl and dialog popups

Tags: ssl, curl, jenkins, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to interact/bypass a dialog popup when running a curl command?

My example involves running a curl command within a jenkins build that is using a `p.12` certificate for authentication.

```
curl -v -k -E dev_key.p12:password https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk:443/rest/api/2/issue/MYSTATS-2213
```

So if I do this within my regular terminal I will get a popup first time round asking stating `example wants to access key in your keychain` with `allow/always allow` buttons after which I can make my curl requests uninterrupted. But for some reason when running the same command in a Jenkins pipeline I just get the error (which is the outcome if you press cancel on the popup)

```
SSL can't load the certificate and it's private key
```

Is there a way around this?

UPDATE

So I have found there is a `--cacert` option to pass through which I guess verifies the dev_key but when I export my ca certificate its a `.crt` file. is the right format?

Answer (score 0):

For SSL (https), curl option `-E` expects a certificate in PEM format (not PKCS#12). From man page:

```
   -E, --cert <certificate[:password]>
          [...]
          The certificate must be in PKCS#12 format if using Secure Transport, or 
          PEM format if using any other engine.
          [...]
```